# Better transitive closure of labelled arrow

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrows

I think the answer will be easy, but I haven't found it yet:

I use labelled arrows like `\xrightarrow\tau` a lot.
Sometimes, I need the transitive closure of such relations, which I write
`\xrightarrow\tau^*` but then, the star is way to high, quite above the `\tau`.

How can I put the star at the same height as if I had written `\rightarrow^*`, even when I have a label?

Figures:

[image: arrows]

Comment: While code snippets are useful for explaining, it is best to compose a MWE that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill: my bad. With the tag amsmath, I thought that appropriate packages were obvious, and my question is (I think/thought) orthogonal to the document class.

Comment: Yes it is obvious (in this case), but still takes time to type (and fix typos in my case :-)). It would just be helpful to  also included the code you used to produce the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\Xrightarrow#1#2{\xrightarrow#1{}\negthickspace^#2}
\begin{document}

$ \rightarrow^*$

$ \xrightarrow\tau{}\!\!^* $  

$ \Xrightarrow\tau* $  
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\!\!` is the same as `\negthickspace`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\raisebox` to adjust the height of the `*`. Here is the original and one with `\raisebox`:

[image]

I have also define a macro `\myxrightarrow` that you can use as `\myxrightarrow{\tau}` to get the same effect.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\myxrightarrow}[1]{{\xrightarrow{#1}}\raisebox{0.4ex}{\scriptsize*}}%
\begin{document}
$\xrightarrow\tau^*$

${\xrightarrow\tau}\raisebox{0.4ex}{\scriptsize *}$

$\myxrightarrow{\tau}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had something similar, but I put the `\tau` in the `\raisebox` to make it have zero height.  That way, one doesn't have to guess the vertical offset (but the resulting shape might be smaller than it really is).

Comment: use another font size and it will be funny ...

Answer (score 3):

Here's another version which defines a new arrow, `\xrighttransarrow` (maybe there's a better name ...).  This is an extensible arrow modelled on the definition of `\xrightarrow` which makes the `*` a part of the arrow, rather than a decoration to be added on afterwards.  There's a bit of jiggery-pokery to get the spacing right: the `*` has to be ignored as far as the placement of the `\tau` is concerned, but then it has to be taken into account when positioning the arrow with its surrounding text.  I may well have messed up those bits as I'm no expert on lengths.  It's also possible that it would go wrong in different maths styles.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\arrow@ht
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\(\rightarrow\)}
\arrow@ht\ht\@tempboxa
\newdimen\star@wd
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\(\scriptstyle *\)}
\star@wd\wd\@tempboxa
\def\righttransarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar{\raisebox{0pt}[\arrow@ht][0pt]{\(\rightarrow^*\hskip-\star@wd\)}}}
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\(\rightarrow\)}
\arrow@ht\ht\@tempboxa
\newcommand{\xrighttransarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\righttransarrowfill@{#1}{#2}\hskip\star@wd}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\(
a\rightarrow^* b
a\xrightarrow\tau^* b
a\xrightarrow{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\(\scriptstyle\tau\)}}^* b
a \xrighttransarrow\tau b
\)
\end{document}
```

Here's the result (note that there's also another `\raisebox` solution in the middle there):

[image: transitive closure arrow]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler definition

```
\newcommand{\tto}[1][]{\mathrel{
  \vphantom{\xrightarrow{#1}}
  \smash{\xrightarrow{#1}}
  \vphantom{\to}^*}
}

$\tto$
$\tto[\tau]$
```

[image]